# How to give width & height as an final argument for Image.asset in StatefulWidget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to pass Width and Height argument as final so that each image can be given its own independent argument.
Images i am using has to be used with it given respective width and height.

main.dart

`DragObj(imag: "img/2.png",position: lips,),` // Want to add width and height here as an argument

dragobj.dart

```
  class DragObj extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imag;
  final Offset position;
  final Double wid;
  final Double hig;
  DragObj({this.imag,this.position,this.wid,this.hig});

  @override
  _DragObj createState() => _DragObj();
}
class _DragObj extends State<DragObj>{
  Offset pos;
  @override
  void initState() {
    pos = widget.position;
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: pos.dy,
        left: pos.dx,
        child: Draggable(
            child: Image.asset(widget.imag, width: 50,height: 50,), // want to pass wid and hig as argument 
            feedback: Opacity(
              opacity: 0.5,
              child: Image.asset(widget.imag, width: 50,height: 50,),
            ),
          onDraggableCanceled: (view, offset){
              setState(() {
                pos=offset;
              });
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know the question is confusing but not getting how to frame it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You already have `wid` and `hig` on your Widget. So you can just pass it as an argument no?

Comment: Final width and height ie wid and hig is giving me error as Compiler message: Error: Type 'Double' not found.
  final Double wid;  i am not getting how to pass it as a argument in Image.Asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declarations are slightly wrong.

change:
`final Double wid;`
to:
`final double wid;`

Then you can just assign them to the Image like you did with the Image source.

Comment: Thank you it worked i am getting my hands on flutter so messed up sorry

Comment: @H.parka No worries. Dart has some differences in spelling of types. Most common types are spelled in lowercase, but String and DateTime for instance are uppercase.

Comment: Exactly Thank you for helping out in just useless question

Answer (score 0):

You can assign height directly to the image widget

```
 child: Image.asset(widget.imag, width: widget.wid,height: widget.hig,)
```

Comment: it needs importing import 'dart:ffi'; when i import i shows error in the solution u provided... removing the import gives me error as Compiler message: Error: Type 'Double' not found.
  final Double wid;

Comment: change as Double to double, syntax issue you have there

Comment: change from Double to double